# Comparing multiple columns of data using pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, compare

I have a pandas data frame df1

```
Time   sat1  sat2 sat3  sat4    val1  val2  val3   val4
10      2     4    2     4       0.1  -1.0   1     2.0
20      3     1    1     3       1.6   0     2.1   -0.7
30      12    8    8     16      0.5   1.1   0.6    2.0
40      2     1    2     12      1.0   1.2   0.4    3.7
```

I want to compare sat1,sat2 with sat3 and sat4 at all time instant.
If there is match between these two columns ,I want to get number of matched
elements and subtract matched elements values columns.

Expected Output:

```
 match_count         Reslt_1           Reslt_2
 2                 val1-val3         val2-val4
 2                 val1-val4         val2-val3
 1                 Nan               val2-val3
 1                 val1-val3          Nan       ( w.r.t match found in sat1 or sat2)
```

These data are sample data and number of columns may increase . Data in sat1,sat2 are toggling in sat3 & sat4 and that is why subtraction will happen accordingly.

How can I obtain above expected output using pandas. I obtained above dataframe 
using pandas concat function.